# Store very large JSON Object in memory while parsing uploaded CSV file (approx. 8GB) on the UI

Tags: javascript, json, csv, fileapi, papaparse

I have a functionality where the user can browse CSV file **approx. size 8GB** on the UI. Once the UI has the `File` object I used **Papa Parse** to parse the CSV file, which works like a charm.

While parsing I am constructing an *object* from each CSV record by doing some manipulation on data. As the parsing proceeds, the size on the *object* keeps on increasing and ultimately parsing fails with browser displaying **out of memory exception**.

The *object* size constructed will be pretty less around 2 GB after data manipulation of CSV but it fails even before this. **Is there a way to handle such large objects on the UI?**

Answer (score 0):

You may not be using the parser correctly

[Did I mention the file is huge?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x2YW.png)

See All configuration : https://www.papaparse.com/docs#config

Try with **worker: true**
 The most typical reason to use a web worker is if your web page becomes unresponsive during parsing. In other words, if it freezes and you can't click things or the scrolling becomes choppy.

Comment: I am parsing in chunks using *papaparse* which works fine and below is the code -

`
    Papa.parse(this.uploadedFile, <PapaParse.ParseConfig>{
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            chunk: this.onChunkParsed,
            complete: this.onParseComplete
        });
`

The code works perfectly for smaller data sets so it should not be an issue with parsing. The concern here is not with the page being responsive but rather storing such huge parsed data object in **memory**.

Comment: Can you share parseConfig

Comment: `{"header":true,"skipEmptyLines":true,"chunk":this.onChunkParsed,"complete":this.onParseComplete}`